# ASP.Net Membership and User Managment

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, membership

My database 'ClinicDB' is Visual studio's local db and i ran 'aspnet_regsql' on it so i have all membership stored procedures and tables and also have my 'client_tbl' and 'doctor_tbl' that i created them to store more data with a 'user_id' field.
I'm new in this asp membership technology how can i add user in 'asp_membership' table and also in doctor or client table with the user id that 'asp_membership' generates after creating a user. Should i use membership class?

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(UsernameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text);
```

then how can i insert the client or doctor data in their table? should i create the user then retrieve the 'user_Id' and insert it in Client and Doctor table with their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already answered your own question. This line...

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(UsernameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text);
```

will effectively create the new user in the membership database. Then, notice the object returned from the method call is the newly-created user which exposes a property named `ProviderUserKey`. This property holds the underlying user id which you will need to cast to whatever data type the membership provider uses usually a `GUID` or an `Integer`

```
Guid userId = new Guid(newUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
```

or

```
int userId = (int)newUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

Then, you can add the required info to your business-specific tables (Client, Doctor). Another approach will be extending the membership system, but this will require a bit more effort on your side